# ASP.net from code behind post data and bring up new window

Tags: asp.net, post, code-behind

I am porting a launcher from classic asp.  In this launcher the user selects criteria and presses a button and a new window running the appropriate page appears.  Essential the classic ASP code does submit of :

```
<form action="aba.asp" method="post" target="mynewpage">
```

I need to do this now in ASP.net web forms.  I have figured out that can open a URL in a new window via a bit of code that call RegisterStartupScript.

```
    Dim js As String = "var w=window.open('" & ReportURL & "'); w.focus();"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnEnter, Page.GetType(), "OpenReportWindow", js, True)
```

But, with this script I am passing the data as part of the URL.  I now need to pass the data via POST and create a new window.  How can I do that?

Note the current target page is classic ASP so the data must be in the request.
Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: What you are looking for is called cross page posting, and is do-able in asp.net. Please see:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1. You can still set the target attribute on the form too. Also be aware that opening new windows unexpectedly is generally considered a bad practice.

Comment: Jon.  Thanks for the information. I tried the button and it opened a window, but did not receive any data. It seemed like the data was not in the request? My target page is an classic ASP page, not ASPX. So the data needs to be in the POST request.